# Are tamely ramified representations $\widehat{\mathbb{Q}_p^\text{tr}}$-admissible?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, group-cohomology, local-fields

Let $K$ be a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $G_K$ denote the absolute Galois group of $K$, $I_K$ the inertia subgroup and $I_K^{(p)}$ the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $I_K$, i.e. the wild ramification group. Let us denote the maximal unramified extension by $K^\text{nr}$ and the maximal tamely ramified extension by $K^{tr}$. It is true that we have
$$ H^1 (G_K/I_K, \operatorname{GL}_d(\widehat{\mathbb{Q}_p^\text{nr}}))=0. $$
Does there exist a similar result for $I^{(p)}_K$? I.e. do we have $$  H^1 (G_K/I_K^{(p)}, \operatorname{GL}_d(\widehat{\mathbb{Q}_p^\text{tr}}))=0 ?$$

Comment: What does the hat indicate?

Comment: @LSpice The $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{nr}}$ resp. $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\mathrm{tr}}$